# Neofetch missing some Infos Debian11

Tags: debian, gnome

as i installed Debian 11 and with it Gnome3 and its dependencies i installed neofetch to have an overview over my System.

The weird thing is that some Infos are missing, like what Windows manager i am using or what DE i am using.

Here is the log of the command `neofetch -vv`

```
+ err 'Neofetch command: /usr/bin/neofetch -vv'
++ color 1
++ case $1 in
++ printf '%b\e[3%sm' '\e[0m' 1
+ err+='[!]\e[0m Neofetch command: /usr/bin/neofetch -vv
'
+ err 'Neofetch version: 7.1.0'
++ color 1
++ case $1 in
++ printf '%b\e[3%sm' '\e[0m' 1
+ err+='[!]\e[0m Neofetch version: 7.1.0
'
+ [[ on == on ]]
+ printf %b '[!]\e[0m Config: Sourced user config.    (/root/.config/neofetch/config.conf)
[!]\e[0m Image: Imagemagick not found, falling back to ascii mode.
[!]\e[0m Info: Couldn'\''t detect DE.
[!]\e[0m Info: Couldn'\''t detect WM.
[!]\e[0m Info: Couldn'\''t detect WM Theme.
[!]\e[0m Info: Couldn'\''t detect Theme.
[!]\e[0m Info: Couldn'\''t detect Icons.
[!]\e[0m Info: Couldn'\''t detect Terminal Font.
[!]\e[0m Neofetch command: /usr/bin/neofetch -vv
[!]\e[0m Neofetch version: 7.1.0
'
[!] Config: Sourced user config.    (/root/.config/neofetch/config.conf)
[!] Image: Imagemagick not found, falling back to ascii mode.
[!] Info: Couldn't detect DE.
[!] Info: Couldn't detect WM.
[!] Info: Couldn't detect WM Theme.
[!] Info: Couldn't detect Theme.
[!] Info: Couldn't detect Icons.
[!] Info: Couldn't detect Terminal Font.
[!] Neofetch command: /usr/bin/neofetch -vv
[!] Neofetch version: 7.1.0
+ [[ off == on ]]
+ return 0
+ printf '\e[?25h\e[?7h'
```

Googling the issue or the logmessages did not help me at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re running `neofetch` as root, which is why it can’t determine information relating to your desktop; run it as the user logged in to your desktop environment.

Comment: oof, thank you. First Linux with a Desktop Enviroment. Will mark this Answer as Solution in 5 Minutes. Thanks for the fast response.